# Plotting an Extrapolation Curve in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset showing user growth on our website over time, like below:

```
Date        New_Users  Cumulative_Total
2012-03-01  10         10
2012-03-02  4          14
2012-03-03  9          23
2012-03-04  21         44
```

Which is then plotted on a line graph within an SSRS report.  I need to extrapolate the data in order to estimate the date the cumulative total will reach a given amount based on the current trend.  I've used calculated series in SSRS before however I see there is no option to add an extrapolation curve.

Does anyone know a way of showing an extrapolation curve on an SSRS chart, either through SSRS itself, custom code on SSRS or (god forbid) calculated in T-SQL?

Comment: What algorithm do you need to use to do your extrapolation?  Linear regression?  Polynomial regresion?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation

Comment: I won't pretend to be an expert on this; however polynomial extrapolation appears to be what I'm after.  Plotting a line through the data that continues on to a pre-defined date; taking into account the whole data set but giving greater weighting to the values that occur closer to the pre-defined date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality for this in SSRS charts. I think the easiest path would be to calculate the trend as a series in a dataset, T-SQL or Analysis Services. Another possibility is to create a data processing extension for SSRS and create the trend in .NET, but I think the overhead of implementation would outweigh writing this as a query.

A quick search on `SQL Trend` showed a few promising results, such as http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=77311